# ip route not showing all route

Tags: networking, ip

I started a docker container, where a VPN client was running. In order to use the VPN inside the container, I added a route to the host route table:

```
$ sudo ip route add 123.123.123.123 via 172.17.0.2 mtu 1400 table 3
```

`172.17.0.2` is the address of the container. After adding the route I had no trouble using the VPN.

However, I cannot see the route in the output of `ip route`:

```
❯ ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp3s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.42 metric 100 
192.168.12.0/24 dev wlp0s20f0u1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.12.1
```

Adding the same route again produced a error, which meant the route indeed had been added to the route table.:

```
❯ sudo ip route add 123.123.123.123 via 172.17.0.2 mtu 1400 table 3
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

The question is:

- Why can't I see the route added in the output of `ip route` when it's actually added to the route table?
- How can I see the route added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you explicitly added the route to a different routing table, and `ip route show` only shows the default table by default.

It's been some years since I messed with routing tables, but I think showing the table you added the route to is as simple as `ip route show table 3`.